# How is the constant being set?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to understand the following code, but cannot get what exactly the line `const ej2_popups_1 = require("@syncfusion/ej2-popups");` is doing? I searched online and found that the require statement is loading a module, but then the question comes up what exactly is the use of `const ej2_popups_1` and which object i.e. full name like aaa.bbb.ccd.Dialog it represents.

The reason I need the fully qualified name is because I want to override a method called `someMethod` in ej2_popups_1.Dialog.prototype.someMethod.

```
const ej2_popups_1 = require("@syncfusion/ej2-popups");

/**
 * Modal Dialog sample
 */
// Rendering modal Dialog by enabling 'isModal' as true
let dialogObj = new ej2_popups_1.Dialog({
    width: '92%',
    header: 'Software Update',
    content: 'Your current software version is up to date.Your current software version is up to date.Your current software version is up to date.Your current software version is up to date.Your current software version is up to date.Your current software version is up to date.Your current software version is up to date.Your current software version is up to date.Your current software version is up to date.Your current software version is up to date.d ',
    target: document.getElementById('target'),
    isModal: true,
    animationSettings: { effect: 'None' },
    buttons: [{
            click: dlgButtonClick,
            buttonModel: { content: 'OK', isPrimary: true }
        }],
    open: dialogOpen,
    close: dialogClose
});
```

Comment: `require("@syncfusion/ej2-popups");` returns whatever is on `module.exports` in that file ... which is then assigned to `ej2_popups_1`

Comment: By in that file, you mean the file being loaded by require?

Comment: yes, sorry, I should've been clearer, instead of "that file" I should've said `"@syncfusion/ej2-popups"`

Comment: Is `"@syncfusion/ej2-popups"` an alias for the actual JavaScript file?

Comment: no, it's a **file** - maybe not called exactly that ... are you actually using nodejs - if so, read the description of the requirejs tag to realise why you've used the wrong tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the RequireJS pattern, you don't have to define things as globals, but rather you have two globals: require and define, which let you create and use modules.

from RequireJS docs: https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define

> A module is different from a traditional script file in that it defines a well-scoped object that avoids polluting the global namespace. It can explicitly list its dependencies and get a handle on those dependencies without needing to refer to global objects, but instead receive the dependencies as arguments to the function that defines the module.

so, this require function does the work of "window" - in that it knows about your other dependencies. and its not as tightly coupled - a variable vs something configurable like a lookup based on a string name of a package/module. the mechanics of how it works are described [here](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#mechanics) as well

Comment: in short, there might be a "full name like aaa.bbb.ccd.Dialog"

Comment: Can I know the full name using some JavaScript property while debugging the code that breaks at the line mentioned in question? I tried the property constructor, but it doesn;t help.

Comment: i would try to get at it using the chrome devtools line debugger (e.g. setting a breakpoint), or just by console logging it, and using the devtools console - right click and save as variable - then you can call .toString() on functions and see their source code. but even better than that is consulting some kind of official reference - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@syncfusion/ej2-popups

Comment: Ok, great. I added some more context to my OP. My main goal is to override an existing method on `Dialog.prototype.someMethod`, but I cannot get a handle to Dialog object in my web page code.

Comment: ok, now i really don't get what is going on :) you have the variable, feel free to override the prototype :) - `const ej2_popups_1 = require("@syncfusion/ej2-popups");` ok, great, now: `let superMethod = ej2_popups_1.Dialog.prototype.someMethod; ej2_popups_1.prototype.Dialog.someMethod = function someMethodOverride() { console.log('overridden!!'); superMethod.apply(this, arguments); };` (disclaimer: pseudocode, but i think it should work or be close)

Comment: I get your code. But the only problem is that the code I posted is being autogenerated and injected into the web page. When I try to refer to `window.ej2_popups_1` in Chrome debugger after the constant has been set then it says its `not available`. So, getting a handle to the constant is my problem. I guess, I have to refer to the constant in my custom code without using the window object since const and let do not appear under window object unlike a var.

Comment: hmm, not sure what to suggest next